# Python script called in C by system() can't send variable to file

Tags: python, c, embedded

My Python script that is called in C function by system() can't export variable to file.
Both files have 777 accesses on my Beaglebone platform.
When I call the script on Beaglebone it is working fine but when I calling this by system() in C function it isn't updating the "buf" file. Why?

Here is the call function:

```
#define luxreadpy "/usr/bin/python /root/LED_Tester_V1/LuxRead/lux.py"

system(luxreadpy);
```

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import smbus
import decimal
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
addr = 0x23
data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr,0x11)
lux2 = str((data[1] + (256 * data[0])) / 1.2)
lux = decimal.Decimal(lux2).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'),     rounding=decimal.R$
outlux = str(lux)
f = open('buf', 'w')
f.write(outlux + '\n')
f.close()
print outlux
```

Comment: Try checking the return value of `system(luxreadpy);`.

Comment: Maybe the python script creates the file in a different directory than you expect. As you specify a file name `'buf'` only, it will be in the current working directory. Check if it works with an absolute file name, e.g. `f = open('/tmp/buf', 'w')`. Print the working directory before `system(luxreadpy);`.

Comment: The "print outlux" value is correct and it's updating.

Comment: @Bodo Your solution works, thank you.

Comment: If you mean that using an absolute path works, then the working directory when executing the script is probably not what you expect. You could also call `chdir()` before `system()` to fix this. It is impossible to give a more specific answer as we don't know how exactly you call your script directly or your program and what you do in your program before `system()`